# use local env to replace variables in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, user-data

I have some variables i will like to replace in userdata of cloudformation template and i do not want to put these variables as parameters in cloudformation.
How can i do this?
Seems cloudformation wants one to always include any variable that need to be replaced as parameters but i feel this is not flexible enough. So not sure if someone else has figured out a way to do this.

Certain variables do not really need to tie to the infrastructure but there is need to replace those variables dynamically.

for example is i have this userdata

```
UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe

            cat >> /tmp/docker_compose.yaml  << EOF
            version: '3.5'
            services:
               ngnix:
                 container_name: nginx
                 image: nginx:$TAG
                 restart: always
                 ports:
                  - 80:80
                 environment:
                    SERVER_ID: $SERVER_ID
                    AWS_REGION: $AWS_REGION 
            EOF
```

and i want to be set the env variable values on the machine from where the cloudformation command will be ran

```
export TAG=1.9.9
export SERVER_ID=12
export AWS_REGION=us-east-1
```

How can i use these local env values to be replaced in the userdata without having those variables as parameters. I already tried all i can think of and i could not do this.

So wanted to tap into the power of internet if someone has thought of a way or hack.

Thanks

Comment: This is where a deployment tool like Ansible would come in handy, you can store variables outside of cloudformation and have Ansible replace the variables.
Would you rather do this in bash though?

Comment: i know about ansible but i am more focused on just cloudformation for now..i am very aware of ansible...bash as in use something like `sed`? or what you have in mind?

Comment: which environment exactly do the variables come from? are they 'outside' the stack, for example on the machine that's initiating the creation of the stack from the template? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it via a script, there may be situations in which this script will give issues, but you'll have to test and see.

I don't want the environment variables being available outside of preparing my cloudformation script - so I've done everything inside one script file; loading the environment variables and substitution.

**Note:** You will need to install envsubst on your machine.

I have 3 files to start off with:
File one is my cloudformation script, in which I have a default value for each one of my parameters expressed as a bash variable:

**cloudformation.yaml**

```
Region
  Default: $Region

InstanceType
  Default: $InstanceType

Colour:
  Default: $Colour
```

Then I have my variables file:

**variables.txt**

```
InstanceType=t2.micro
Colour=Blue
Region=eu-west-1
```

Then I have my script that does the substitution:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source variables.txt
export $(cut -d= -f1 variables.txt)

cat cloudformation.yaml | envsubst > subs_cloudformation.yaml
```

This is the contents of my folder:

```
cloudformation.yaml    script.sh     variables.txt
```

I make sure my script.sh has the correct permissions:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

And run my script:

```
./script.sh
```

The contents of my folder is now:

```
cloudformation.yaml     script.sh     variables.txt     subs_cloudformation.yaml
```

And if I view the contents of my subs_cloudformation.yaml file:

```
Region
  Default: eu-west-1

InstanceType
  Default: t2.micro

Colour:
  Default: Blue
```

I can now run that cloudformation script, and cloudformation will do the job of substituting those defaults into my template - so all we're doing with the above script is giving cloudformation the defaults.

I've of course just given a snippet of the cloudformation template, you can further improve this by having a dev.txt, qa.txt, production.txt file of variables and substitute whichever one in.

Edit: It doesn't matter where in the file your variable is though, so it can be in userdata or parameters as default.. doesn't matter. You will also need to be careful, this won't check if you have a matching environment variable for every variable in your cloudformation file. If it isn't in your variable file, the substituted value will just be blank.

Comment: i dont want to install anything or have some special prerequisites..i can easily use `sed` but just wanted to check maybe there is some cloudformation feature am not aware of..if this is not natively possible then will just use something like `sed`

Comment: Ok - suggested an edit on your question as you do not state that you do not want to install any applications or packages, or that you know how to use `sed` and are looking for alternatives

Comment: Also, check if envsubst isn't already installed on your system. I understand that it is on some linux systems.